# How can we get the comment of the NSLocalizedString?

Tags: swift

If we have this code:

```
let a = NSLocalizedString("Hi", comment: "Hello")
```

Is there a way to print the comment of the variable a?
like:

```
print(a...) = "Hello"
```

Comment: Why do you need the comment at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The comment only appears in the strings file generated by scanning your code for occurrences of `NSLocalizedString`. It's not a value you can obtain at runtime. The return value of `NSLocalizedString` is `String` and it is just the localized string.

The only use of the comment is to help translators when translating the original strings file into other languages.